# How can execute several commands in doSetTimeout function?

Tags: javascript

```
doSetTimeout = (value, timer) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      value
    }, timer);
  }
```

call doSetTimeout here:

```
let Data = [
{"name":"John","age":"25"},
{"name":"Alex","age":"31"},
{"name":"Rose","age":"18"},
]

sendData = () => {
   for(let i=0; i<Data.length; i++) {
      doSetTimeout(
       ()=> {
          var myHeaders = new Headers();
          myHeaders.append("token", this.state.Token);
          myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
          let Data = JSON.stringify(Data[i]);
          var requestOptions = {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: myHeaders,
            body: Data,
            redirect: 'follow'
          };
          fetch(sycnAddress + "Data", requestOptions)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then((responseJson) => {
              console.log(responseJson);
              return responseJson;
            })
            .catch((error) => {
              console.log(error);
            });
       }
     , i*3000);
   }
}
```

I want the data one by one sent to the server with an interval of 3 seconds
But this function has a problem and the data is not sent!

Comment: Try to use `setInterval` instead.

Comment: `value` in `doSetTimeout` is a function, therefor you have to call it.

Comment: And why `doSetTimeout` at all? It would do exactly the same as `setTimeout`.

Comment: Sarthak Aggarwal  I used it before but didn't get an answer

Comment: Andreas, It didn't work right inside the for loop and I had to

Answer (score 0):

Try this with using closure singleton function inside

```
let Data = [
{"name":"John","age":"25"},
{"name":"Alex","age":"31"},
{"name":"Rose","age":"18"},
]

sendData = () => {
   for(let i=0; i<Data.length; i++) {

      (function(indx){

        setTimeout(function(){

        var myHeaders = new Headers();
          myHeaders.append("token", this.state.Token);
          myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
          let Data = JSON.stringify(Data[i]);
          var requestOptions = {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: myHeaders,
            body: Data,
            redirect: 'follow'
          };
          fetch(sycnAddress + "Data", requestOptions)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then((responseJson) => {
              console.log(responseJson);
              return responseJson;
            })
            .catch((error) => {
              console.log(error);
            });


        }, 3000 * indx);

      }(i));



   }
}
```

Comment: @behi1989 can you see any errors in console? Can you see that at least one request to sycnAddress + "Data" enpoint?